# Clear a list or dictionary in Angularjs with a key, value structure

Tags: javascript, angularjs

A very basic question, I have a list or dictionary in AngularJS with a key,value structure like this:

```
$scope.itemList = {}
```

This list fills with data coming from a JSON file, what I need to do is to clear this list at some point but I dont know how to do it,

I tried the following but didnt worked.

```
$scope.itemList.clear()
```

Some help would be great.

> Note: I said a list but actually is an object what I have because of
>   the {}, I'll leave the question as is, someone can think in a wrong
>   way as I did.

Comment: just set `$scope.itemList={}`

Comment: Thanks, for your time  =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing is that declaring variable with `{}` means object not list.

To clear a object you have to re-define it again

```
$scope.itemList = {}
```

To declare a list you have to use like this

```
$scope.itemList = [];
```

And to clear list

Try like this

```
$scope.itemList.length=0;
```

or re-declare it again.

```
$scope.itemList = [];
```

If you need `.clear()` method on your code, you can create extension method

Like this

```
Array.prototype.clear=function(){
  this.length=0;
}
$scope.itemList.clear();
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, you were right, I said "List" but I'm using an object, so thank for the answer and the correction on how I made my question, I leave a note on my question.

Comment: @kennechu I have added a extension method concept you can use that.

Answer (score 1):

> In JavaScript, for non-primitive data type, **clearing** and **setting to
>   new empty value** have a very different behavior.

**Array Example**

```
$scope.itemList = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
var myArr = $scope.itemList;

// Setting to a new empty array,
$scope.itemList = [];

console.log(myArr); // The value is still ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

**Object Example**

```
$scope.itemList = {'A': 1, 'B': 2};
var myObj = $scope.itemList;

// Setting to a new empty object,
$scope.itemList = {};

console.log(myObj); // The value is still {'A': 1, 'B': 2}
```

Please also consider the examples above may cause issue by variables that currently use `$scope.itemList`. *(Unless you don't care what happens to them)*

This is my suggestion as the best way to really **clear** an array or object.

```
// Clear an array
$scope.itemList.splice(0, $scope.itemList.length);

// Clear an object
for (var prop in $scope.itemList) {
    if ($scope.itemList.hasOwnProperty(prop)) { 
        delete $scope.itemList[prop];
    }
}
```

In this way, any variables which assigned its value from `$scope.itemList`, will also be cleared. And I found this as a good practice *(e.g. auto-populating combo box in angularJS)*.

Comment: Thanks for your time and the detail on your answer =)

Comment: @kennechu I see that `$scope.itemList` is an object. I have updated my post.

Comment: Thank's, I really appreciate your help and your time :)